# Need assitance with menu code

Tags: vbscript

New to scripting and need some help.

Have script with 9 menu choices (1-9), I need to menu to stay open (displayed on the users screen) if they select and run anything from 1-8, but if they select item 9, I need it to exit.

Thank you in advance !

```
Titre = "Select One Item - IT Config Dept 2016"
"Select One at a Time"&vbcr&vbcr&_
"1 - Map Mastercd "&vbcr&_
"2 - Shortcuts "&vbcr&_
"3 - Customize Windows "&vbcr&_
"4 - IE Setup "&vbcr&_
"5 - Notetab "&vbcr&_
"6 - Outlook Setup "&vbcr&_
"7 - AS400 & New GUI "&vbcr&_
"8 - AMS "&vbcr&_
"9 - Exit "

Default ="1"
Question = InputBox(message,Titre,Default)
Select Case Question 
Case 1 Run(1)
Case 2 Run(2)
Case 3 Run(3)
Case 4 Run(4)
Case 5 Run(5)
Case 6 Run(6)
Case 7 Run(7)
Case 8 Run(8)
Case 9 Run(9)


end Select


Sub Run(var)
Set WS = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
    Select Case var
    Case 1    WS.run("\\usprsfs11\IT\IT_notes\!PC_ConfigDoc\Bryan\Autohotkey\64_bit_Menu\Mapping_Mastercd\Mapping_Mastercd.bat")
    Case 2 WS.run("\\usprsfs11\IT\IT_notes\!PC_ConfigDoc\Bryan\Autohotkey\64_bit_Menu\Shortcuts_done\Shortcuts.bat")
    Case 3 WS.run("\\usprsfs11\IT\IT_notes\!PC_ConfigDoc\Bryan\Autohotkey\64_bit_Menu\Setup_done\Taskbar_combined.vbs")
    Case 4 WS.run("\\usprsfs11\IT\IT_notes\!PC_ConfigDoc\Bryan\Autohotkey\64_bit_Menu\Iexplorer_done\IE_setup.vbs")
    Case 5 WS.run("\\usprsfs11\IT\IT_notes\!PC_ConfigDoc\Bryan\Autohotkey\64_bit_Menu\Notepab_done\Notetab_combined.vbs")
    Case 6 WS.run("\\usprsfs11\IT\IT_notes\!PC_ConfigDoc\Bryan\Autohotkey\64_bit_Menu\Outlook_done\Outlook.vbs")
    Case 7 WS.run("\\usprsfs11\IT\IT_notes\!PC_ConfigDoc\Bryan\Autohotkey\64_bit_Menu\AS400\ASW_Setup.vbs")
    Case 8 WS.run("\\usprsfs11\IT\IT_notes\!PC_ConfigDoc\Bryan\Autohotkey\64_bit_Menu\AMS_done\AMS_combined.vbs")
    Case 9 WS.run("Exit code")

End select
End Sub 

'  case 1

Sub Mapping(Process)
Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Command = "cmd /c Taskkill /F /IM "&Process&""
Execution = Ws.Run(Command,0,False)
End Sub

' case 2

Sub Shortcuts(Process)
Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Command = "cmd /c Taskkill /F /IM "&Process&""
Execution = Ws.Run(Command,0,False)
End Sub

Function CmdPrompt(sCmd)
Dim sCmdLine,oWS,nRes
set oWS = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
sCmdLine = "cmd /c Start " & sCmd & ""
nRes = oWS.Run(sCmdLine,0,False)
CmdPrompt = nRes
End Function

' case 3

Sub Customizewindows(Process)
Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Command = "cmd /c Taskkill /F /IM "&Process&""
Execution = Ws.Run(Command,0,False)
End Sub

Function CmdPrompt(sCmd)
Dim sCmdLine,oWS,nRes
set oWS = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
sCmdLine = "cmd /c Start " & sCmd & ""
nRes = oWS.Run(sCmdLine,0,False)
CmdPrompt = nRes
End Function

' case 4 

Sub IEsetup(Process)
Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Command = "cmd /c Taskkill /F /IM "&Process&""
Execution = Ws.Run(Command,0,False)
End Sub

Function CmdPrompt(sCmd)
Dim sCmdLine,oWS,nRes
set oWS = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
sCmdLine = "cmd /c Start " & sCmd & ""
nRes = oWS.Run(sCmdLine,0,False)
CmdPrompt = nRes
End Function

' case 5

Sub Notetab(Process)
Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Command = "cmd /c Taskkill /F /IM "&Process&""
Execution = Ws.Run(Command,0,False)
End Sub

Function CmdPrompt(sCmd)
Dim sCmdLine,oWS,nRes
set oWS = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
sCmdLine = "cmd /c Start " & sCmd & ""
nRes = oWS.Run(sCmdLine,0,False)
CmdPrompt = nRes
End Function

' case 6

Sub Outlook(Process)
Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Command = "cmd /c Taskkill /F /IM "&Process&""
Execution = Ws.Run(Command,0,False)
End Sub

Function CmdPrompt(sCmd)
Dim sCmdLine,oWS,nRes
set oWS = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
sCmdLine = "cmd /c Start " & sCmd & ""
nRes = oWS.Run(sCmdLine,0,False)
CmdPrompt = nRes
End Function

' case 7

Sub AS400(Process)
Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Command = "cmd /c Taskkill /F /IM "&Process&""
Execution = Ws.Run(Command,0,False)
End Sub

Function CmdPrompt(sCmd)
Dim sCmdLine,oWS,nRes
set oWS = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
sCmdLine = "cmd /c Start " & sCmd & ""
nRes = oWS.Run(sCmdLine,0,False)
CmdPrompt = nRes
End Function

' case 8

Sub AMS(Process)
Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Command = "cmd /c Taskkill /F /IM "&Process&""
Execution = Ws.Run(Command,0,False)
End Sub

Function CmdPrompt(sCmd)
Dim sCmdLine,oWS,nRes
set oWS = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
sCmdLine = "cmd /c Start " & sCmd & ""
nRes = oWS.Run(sCmdLine,0,False)
CmdPrompt = nRes
End Function
```

Comment: Please see [mcve] and [ask], and try to [edit] your question to narrow it down to a *specific* issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a loop that exits on 9

```
    while Question <> 9
        Question = InputBox(message,Titre,Default)

        Select Case Question 
            Case 1 Run(1)
            Case 2 Run(2)
            Case 3 Run(3)
            Case 4 Run(4)
            Case 5 Run(5)
            Case 6 Run(6)
            Case 7 Run(7)
            Case 8 Run(8)
            Case 9 Run(9)
        end Select

    wend
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that :

```
Title="Menu Selector : IT Config Dept 2016"
message = "Select One at a Time"&vbcr&vbcr&_
"1 - Map Mastercd "&vbcr&_
"2 - Shortcuts "&vbcr&_
"3 - Customize Windows "&vbcr&_
"4 - IE Setup "&vbcr&_
"5 - Notetab "&vbcr&_
"6 - Outlook Setup "&vbcr&_
"7 - AS400 & New GUI "&vbcr&_
"8 - AMS "&vbcr&_
"9 - Exit "

Do
    response = InputBox(message,Title,9)
    If response = "" Then WScript.Quit  'Detect Cancel
    If IsNumeric(response) Then Exit Do 'Detect value response.
    MsgBox "You must enter a numeric value.", 48, "Invalid Entry"
Loop

Select Case response 
Case 1 Run(1)
Case 2 Run(2)
Case 3 Run(3)
Case 4 Run(4)
Case 5 Run(5)
Case 6 Run(6)
Case 7 Run(7)
Case 8 Run(8)
Case 9 Run(9)
end Select


Sub Run(var)
Set WS = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
    Select Case var
    Case 1 WS.run("\\usprsfs11\IT\IT_notes\!PC_ConfigDoc\Bryan\Autohotkey\64_bit_Menu\Mapping_Mastercd\Mapping_Mastercd.bat")
    Case 2 WS.run("\\usprsfs11\IT\IT_notes\!PC_ConfigDoc\Bryan\Autohotkey\64_bit_Menu\Shortcuts_done\Shortcuts.bat")
    Case 3 WS.run("\\usprsfs11\IT\IT_notes\!PC_ConfigDoc\Bryan\Autohotkey\64_bit_Menu\Setup_done\Taskbar_combined.vbs")
    Case 4 WS.run("\\usprsfs11\IT\IT_notes\!PC_ConfigDoc\Bryan\Autohotkey\64_bit_Menu\Iexplorer_done\IE_setup.vbs")
    Case 5 WS.run("\\usprsfs11\IT\IT_notes\!PC_ConfigDoc\Bryan\Autohotkey\64_bit_Menu\Notepab_done\Notetab_combined.vbs")
    Case 6 WS.run("\\usprsfs11\IT\IT_notes\!PC_ConfigDoc\Bryan\Autohotkey\64_bit_Menu\Outlook_done\Outlook.vbs")
    Case 7 WS.run("\\usprsfs11\IT\IT_notes\!PC_ConfigDoc\Bryan\Autohotkey\64_bit_Menu\AS400\ASW_Setup.vbs")
    Case 8 WS.run("\\usprsfs11\IT\IT_notes\!PC_ConfigDoc\Bryan\Autohotkey\64_bit_Menu\AMS_done\AMS_combined.vbs")
    Case 9 wscript.quit()
End select
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi and Thank you for the help, but after applying the changes I now get an error message and cannot figure where the problem is in the code. Can you please hceckout my coding to see what I am missing ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that the code runs after I get the error message . If the code doesn't appear please let me know and I will reattach it